# Ways to ask what a word means

Tags: word-order, questions

Are all these idiomatic ways of asking what a word means?

Is number 2 a cleft sentence?

1. What does "technique" mean?
2. What does it mean "technique"?
3. What's the meaning of "technique"?

Comment: #2 isn't a properly-formed sentence. Avoid that construction (but *What does it mean **to be** fungible?* is fine).

Comment: If you really wanted you could write *What does it/this mean: "technique"?* or ask *What does it/this mean, "technique"?* You need to have a pause/punctuation. But in speech 1 and 3 are more likely.

Answer (score 0):

#1 and #3 are fine. #2 as @FumbleFingers has pointed out is incorrect.

@FumbleFingers's example in comment:

> What does it mean to be fungible?

, where *fungible* is the adjective. And no it is not a cleft sentence.

Comment: I don't know how to describe the difference between elements like ***to be fungible, if that happens, to you, in French, today*** (that *can* validly follow *What does it mean...*), and words like OP's ***technique*** (that *can't* be used like that). I was almost going to suggest that ***single words don't work*** - until I thought of ***today***.